# Metrics/AbcSize Too High: How do I decrease the ABC in this method?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rubocop

I have recently started using Rubocop to "standardise" my code, and it has helped me optimise a lot of my code, as well as help me learn a lot of Ruby "tricks". I understand that I should use my own judgement and disable Cops where necessary, but I have found myself quite stuck with the below code:

```
def index
  if params[:filters].present?
    if params[:filters][:deleted].blank? || params[:filters][:deleted] == "false"
      # if owned is true, then we don't need to filter by admin
      params[:filters][:admin] = nil if params[:filters][:admin].present? && params[:filters][:owned] == "true"
      # if admin is true, then must not filter by owned if false
      params[:filters][:owned] = nil if params[:filters][:owned].present? && params[:filters][:admin] == "false"
      companies_list =
        case params[:filters][:admin]&.to_b
        when true
          current_user.admin_companies
        when false
          current_user.non_admin_companies
        end
      if params[:filters][:owned].present?
        companies_list ||= current_user.companies
        if params[:filters][:owned].to_b
          companies_list = companies_list.where(owner: current_user)
        else
          companies_list = companies_list.where.not(owner: current_user)
        end
      end
    else
      # Filters for deleted companies
      companies_list = {}
    end
  end
  companies_list ||= current_user.companies
  response = { data: companies_list.alphabetical.as_json(current_user: current_user) }
  json_response(response)
end
```

Among others, the error that I'm getting is the following:

```
C: Metrics/AbcSize: Assignment Branch Condition size for index is too high. [<13, 57, 16> 60.61/15]
```

I understand the maths behind it, but I don't know how to simplify this code to achieve the same result.

Could someone please give me some guidance on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Rather than comment on this specific bit of code, I would suggest picking up a copy of Refactoring by Martin Fowler, or 99 Bottles of OOP by Sandi Metz. You'll learn a lot about ways to reduce complex code and improve design.

Comment: @AndyWaite Thank you for the suggestion. I looked up the Martin Fowler book that you suggested, and have started reading it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well first and foremost, is this code fully tested, including all the myriad conditions? It's so complex that refactoring will surely be disastrous unless the test suite is rigorous. So, write a comprehensive test suite if you don't already have one. If there's already a test suite, make sure it tests all the conditions.

Second, apply the "fat model skinny controller" paradigm. So move all the complexity into a model, let's call it `CompanyFilter`

```rb
def index
  companies_list = CompanyFilter.new(current_user, params).list
  response = { data: companies_list.alphabetical.as_json(current_user: current_user) }
  json_response(response)
end
```

and move all those if/then/else statements into the `CompanyFilter#list` method

tests still pass? great, you'll still get the Rubocop warnings, but related to the CompanyFilter class.

Now you need to untangle all the conditions. It's a bit hard for me to understand what's going on, but it looks as if it should be reducible to a single case statement, with 5 possible outcomes. So the CompanyFilter class might look something like this:

```rb
class CompanyFilter
  attr_accessors :current_user, :params

  def initialize(current_user, params)
    @current_user = current_user
    @params = params
  end

  def list
    case
    when no_filter_specified
      {}
    when user_is_admin
      @current_user.admin_companies
    when user_is_owned
      # etc
    when # other condition
      # etc
    end
  end

  private
  def no_filter_specified
    @params[:filter].blank?
  end

  def user_is_admin
    # returns boolean based on params hash
  end

  def user_is_owned
    # returns boolean based on params hash
  end
end
```

tests still passing? perfect! [Edit] Now you can move most of your controller tests into a model test for the CompanyFilter class.

Finally I would define all the different companies_list queries as scopes on the Company model, e.g.

```rb
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  # some examples, I don't know what's appropriate in this app
  scope :for_user, ->(user){ where("...") }
  scope :administered_by, ->(user){ where("...") }
end
```

Comment: Yes, I had put in place testing before I even wrote the code for it. I also implemented TDD for this project, and it has paid off ten-fold. I never thought of doing it this way, because it made logical sense to have the conditions in the controller, but the way you suggest makes sense. Also, I thought of "splitting" it into multiple methods, but I felt that was cheating. Your way proposes a better way of handling all filters for all models that need them (and they will). I will test this out and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: kudos for TDD, Theo. I added another note about testing.

Comment: Thanks Les. This worked beautifully and was easy to implement. What's best is that I can use this method for my other filters. And I saw what you did there with the edit haha. Just a question, though: Why would I need to test the `CompanyFilter` on its own? Is it not enough that it is being tested through the request of the `index` action?

Comment: So glad this worked for you, Theo. Please consider designating this as the "accepted answer". You don't need to test CompanyFilter behaviour in both the model and the controller, and yes, it's enough to test it in the controller. In my opinion it's a better way to organise your test specs, to have a spec that just focuses on the model functionality. It's often more performant, but testing the controller is equivalent. Having moved the behaviour to the model, it's "good practice" to move the tests to a model test.

Comment: Here's the thing about testing the model vs. the controller... your tests can be much more granular...  you have decomposed a tangle of if/then/else statements that are hard to test into individual methods that are easy to test. Some devs will even do the next step and refactor their test specs too.

Comment: I understand the reasoning and I know how to test it... The reason I thought it redundant is because I need to test that the filters in the request are returning the correct objects. So testing it as a model test would 3ssentially do the same thing, even though it is the correct thing to do (FYI, I'm knew to testing too, and I'm sure my tests need a lot of refactoring, even though they get the job done).

Answer (score 1):

When composing database scopes [ActiveRecord::SpawnMethods#merge](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods.html#method-i-merge) is your friend.

```
Post.where(title: 'How to use .merge')
    .merge(Post.where(published: true))
```

While it doesn't look like much it lets you programatically compose scopes without overelying on mutating assignment and if/else trees. You can for example compose an array of conditions and merge them together into a single `ActiveRecord::Relation` object with `Array#reduce`:

```
[Post.where(title: 'foo'), Post.where(author: 'bar')].reduce(&:merge)
# => SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."title" = $1 AND "posts"."author" = $2 LIMIT $3
```

So lets combine that with a skinny controllers approach where you handle filtering in a seperate object:

```
class ApplicationFilter
  include ActiveModel::Attributes 
  include ActiveModel::AttributeAssignment 
  attr_accessor :user

  def initialize(**attributes)
    super()
    assign_attributes(attributes)
  end

  # A convenience method to both instanciate and apply the filters
  def self.call(user, params, scope: model_class.all)
    return scope unless params[:filters].present?
    scope.merge(
      new(
        permit_params(params).merge(user: user)
      ).to_scope
    )
  end

  def to_scope
    filters.map { |filter| apply_filter(filter) }
           .compact
           .select {|f| f.respond_to?(:merge) }
           .reduce(&:merge)
  end

  private
  # calls a filter_by_foo method if present or 
  # defaults to where(key => value)
  def apply_filter(attribute)
    if respond_to? "filter_by_#{attribute}"
      send("filter_by_#{attribute}")
    else 
      self.class.model_class.where(
        attribute => send(attribute)
      )
    end
  end
  # Convention over Configuration is sexy.
  def self.model_class 
    name.chomp("Filter").constantize 
  end

  # filters the incoming params hash based on the attributes of this filter class
  def self.permit_params
    params.permit(filters).reject{ |k,v| v.blank? }
  end
  
  # provided for modularity
  def self.filters
    attribute_names
  end
end
```

This uses some of the goodness provided by Rails to setup objects with attributes that will dynamically handle filtering attributes. It looks at the list of attributes you have declared and then slices those off the params and applies a method for that filter if present.

We can then write a concrete implementation:

```
class CompanyFilter < ApplicationFilter
  attribute :admin, :boolean, default: false
  attribute :owned, :boolean 

  private

  def filter_by_admin
    if admin
      user.admin_companies
    else
      user.non_admin_companies
    end
  end

  # this should be refactored to use an assocation on User
  def filter_by_owned
    case owned
    when nil
      nil
    when true
      Company.where(owner: user)
    when false
      Company.where.not(owner: user)
    end
  end
end
```

And you can call it with:

```
# scope is optional
@companies = CompanyFilter.call(current_user, params), scope: current_user.companies)
```

Comment: This is a very elegant solution that would help greatly in making my filters more generic. I will definitely look into it, as it's bringing in a lot of concepts I haven't used before (I tend to stick to simpler code - which of course is not often as efficient).